# pyqt5 drop down list with sub lists

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to figure out how I can create a drop down list (currently using QComoboBox), with a few items, and when I hover my mouse/click on one of the options, it shows a sub list, containing a few more options.
I tried to search online but couldn't find anything that I could use.

Here an example of what I want to achieve (sorry for terrible quality, but I think it makes it clear what my goal is..)
[image]

Does any one have an idea of how to make a sub list inside a list?

**Edit**

After trying @eyllanesc suggestion I still having a problem:
I am using two files: one file that contains all the objects like buttons and such, and the other one that contains some functions and basically makes the GUI functional.

I defined this on my first file

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
  def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(751, 650)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.menuBtn=QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.menuBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 220, 100, 100))

        self.productMenu=QtWidgets.QMenu(self.centralwidget)
        self.menu1=self.productMenu.addMenu("options")
        self.menu1.addAction("option 1")
        self.menu2=self.productMenu.addMenu("option 2")
        self.menu2.addAction("option 2a")
        self.menu2.addAction("option 2b")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

  def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Test"))
        self.menuBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Menu"))
```

And on the second file (the functional) I wrote this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from stackTest import Ui_MainWindow
import sys

class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.productMenu.triggered.connect(lambda action: self.ui.menuBtn.setText(action.text("Hello!")))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   application = ApplicationWindow()
   application.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run the code, I can see the button, but when I click it nothing happens.

How can I make it run so when I push the button I'll get the menu.

Comment: You could place an image or scheme of what you want to get

Comment: @eyllanesc added a picture, thanks!

Comment: @Alon123 What about using a QToolButton (with `setPopupMode(QToolButton.InstantPopup)`) and setting it a QMenu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a button (QPushButton, QToolButton, etc.) and establish a QMenu as I show below:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


def create_menu(d, menu):
    if isinstance(d, list):
        for e in d:
            create_menu(e, menu)
    elif isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            sub_menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(k, menu)
            menu.addMenu(sub_menu)
            create_menu(v, sub_menu)
    else:
        action = menu.addAction(d)
        action.setIconVisibleInMenu(False)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        d = ["1", "2", "3", {"4": ["5", "6", {"7": ["8", "9"]}]}, {"10": "11"}]

        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        create_menu(d, menu)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        button.setMenu(menu)

        menu.triggered.connect(lambda action: button.setText(action.text()))

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addStretch()

        self.resize(640, 480)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code provided by the OP must add the QMenu to the QPushButton:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

from stackTest import Ui_MainWindow


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.menuBtn.setMenu(self.ui.productMenu)
        self.ui.productMenu.triggered.connect(
            lambda action: self.ui.menuBtn.setText(action.text())
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = ApplicationWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi!
I am trying to implement your comment into my code, but I am having a problem:
All of my objects (like buttons and etc.) are in another class which I am import to another script, so I am creating everything by self.
I tried to take some of what you wrote here and try it out on my code (would send code but it's too long for a comment..)

Comment: @Alon123 If you want my help to implement it in a specific code then you must provide a [MRE], otherwise I find it impossible to help you.

Comment: @Alon123 Never put code in the comments (they look horrible), instead edit your question and add it there. I recommend you read [ask] and pass the [tour]

Comment: @Alon123 Your code is not an MRE so I can't help you

Comment: Sorry! But I don't quite understand what is missing... I didn't want to put it the whole code since it's long.. I'll try to add a few things and hopefully that will be sufficient.

Comment: @Alon123 Your code but is not verifiable, the verifiability can be easily verified: Make a copy-paste of the possible MRE (your code provided in your question) in a file and then execute it, if the same thing you have in your original code is reproduced then it is an MRE, otherwise it is not. I did the above with your code and it clearly can't be executed

Comment: I think I understand what you mean and I fixed it. I hope this time it is sufficient but not long. Please inform me if it not good yet. Thank you dearly.

Comment: @Alon123 No, your code is not an MRE. Have you done the exercise I indicated? that is, have you copied your code into a file and were able to execute it?

Comment: I did, it runs for me (but I can't see the button or the list(the list is obvious..), and the name of the file opened is different then what I defined, which is odd because I pretty sure I copied everything needed.. I'll keep trying though)

Also thank you from the bottom of my heart for your kindness and patience.

Comment: It finally works... I mean I now get the button and the change on the window title... yet again, not list when I click the button

Comment: Thank you so much, for the help with the code and also for your help of how to properly ask questions.